# Cannot open Microsoft Access 2013 since last microsoft update

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office

I use Windows 8 and Microsoft Office 365. I can see in Programs and Features that Microsoft Office installed the version 15.0.4631.1002 of Microsoft Office 365. Since then, if I try to open an existing document in Access, it starts opening a pop up window titled Windows Installer, saying preparing install, but then a popup titled Microsoft Visual Basic with the error "The language dll VBE7INTL.DLL could not be found" shows up. It cannot be closed and I cannot have access to Access (sic).

I am at loss with what to do. None of my searches on this error brought me to a solution and I would really like to access my documents (extension .accdb).
Any idea what to do?

Comment: repair Office from the "Programs and Features" dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only fix I found was to reinstall Office.